# Error powershell en visual studio 2017 acceso denegado a la ruta 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\...'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, powershell

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en ASP.NET y tengo varios scripts de powershell para algunas peticiones al graph de microsoft.

Algunos de éstos hacen peticiones y devuelven el resultado escribiéndolo en un txt.
He creado uno que difiere en que la ruta del txt la pongo a mano en vez de pasársela como parámetro.

`$MailArray | Out-File 'C:\\...\powershell_results.txt'`

El problema es que al ejecutar éste último script me da el siguiente error

{Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\NombreDeUnGrupo'.}

El nombre de grupo se lo paso como parámetro y lo llamo path

En en controlador:

 `ps.AddParameter("path", idg);`

En el script:

 `Get-DistributionGroupMember -identity $path`

Agradecería cualquier ayuda para solucionar el error.

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: intenta guardando en disco D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en que estoy trabajando con varias versiones del mismo proyecto en distintas rutas. Quedó una ruta para ejecutar un script que hacía referencia a 
la ruta del mismo script de otra versión. Ésto debió de crear un problema de permisos a la hora de ejecutarlos.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/172467)

Comment: El autor de la pregunta soy yo, quizás no me expliqué bien a la hora de aclarar la solución. Al trabajar con dos versiones del mismo proyecto quedó la ruta residual de uno en otro, el programa intentaba ejecutar el script de un fichero externo y no funcionaba correctamente.

Comment: Tomas, por favor edita la respuesta y agrega detalles para evitar que te la cierren. [Haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas como funciona la comunidad.

Comment: Es correcto responder tu propia pregunta, sin embargo la respuesta ha sido reportada como de baja calidad. Te sugiero leer [answer], editar tu respuesta y añadir mayor detalle para satisfacer los criterios de calidad del sitio. Un saludo y me alegra que encontraras la solución a tu problema y la quieras comprartir :)

Comment: Esto es lo que se considera entonces un problema no reproducible. No habia forma que ninguno de nosotros pudiera ver ese problema.